# How can I solve this logarithms problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that 
$$a^x \cdot b^{2x} \cdot c^{3x} = 2,$$ where $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, then how can I find $x$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you mean $b^{2x}$ and $c^{3x}$?  That is not what you wrote.

Comment: Please check my edit. Is this the correct formula?

Comment: You claim it is a logarithm problem.  So use logarithms.  $\log_2 a^xb^{2x}c^{3x} = \log_2 (2)$ so $x\log_2 a+2x\log_2b +3x\log_2 c = 1$ so $x =\frac 1{\log_2 a  +2 \log_2 b+3\log_2 c}$.  that's an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the logarithm,

$$x\log a+2x\log b+3x\log c=x\,(\log a+2\log b+3\log c)=\log2.$$

Answer (score 0):

You could write

$$a^xb^{2x}c^{3x} = (ab^2c^3)^x =2.$$

Then take natural logs of both sides

$$x \ln(ab^2c^3) =\ln 2.$$

So

$$x= \frac{\ln 2}{\ln(ab^2c^3)}.$$